# Python: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ''

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Here's a part of my script to parse XML files. I am getting the following error and am unable to figure out why. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
txtFile = open("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\DataStage\\JobDefinitions\\fileList.txt",'r')

for eachTxtLine in txtFile:
    xmlFile = open(eachTxtLine.strip(),'r')
............
```

Error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ''
```

Comment: Are there blank lines in `txtFile`?

Comment: You are passing an empty string (`''`) to `open`. The error message even informs you so.

Comment: Yes there was an extra space at the end of the file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably blank lines in `txtFile`. To avoid this, add a check after the `str.strip()`:

```
with open(...) as txtFile:
    for eachTxtLine in txtFile:
        eachTxtLine = eachTxtLine.strip()
        if eachTxtLine:
            with open(eachTxtLine) as xmlFile:
                ...
```

Note the use of the `with` context handler for file IO.

Comment: Good spot. @user3700602 don't forget to accept this answer in about 9 minutes